# linux how to use grep for a variable when in a loop function

Tags: linux, shell, loops, grep

I want to find all function in c file and print those functions, but i do not know how Correct expression to `grep` the variable `$i`

```
find=c
for i in *; do
if [ "${i}" != "${i%.${find}}" ]
    then
    echo "$i"
    grep "^int|^void" "${1}-${i}" | sed 's/{//g'
else
    echo "unable to find any funcitions"
fi 
done
```

Comment: *grep* is the wrong tool for this. First of all, a function definition in C can span several lines (for instance, one style some people advocate, is to write the return value in one line and the function name in the following line), and grep is line-oriented. Second, given the quite complicated way a function is defined, and the fact that C preprocessor macros also can get into your way, I don't think that a function definition can uniquely be described by a regular expression.

Comment: Are you trying to do something more specific than simply listing functions? Because there are tools to do things like listing symbols after compilation and finding unused functions. You really want a tool which parses C files rather than a `grep` for this to be a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the commenters, that tool they speak about is ctags, you might already have it on your system. To get the list of functions:

```
ctags -o - yourFile.c | awk '$4=="f"{print $1}'
```

Comment: sorry i am asking the linux script coding, only grep able to work